# How to center a parent with fixed width in react native in portrait and landscape mode

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

- I am trying to center a parent with fixed width (no padding)containing children element in portrait and landscape mode
- Attaching the expo link for reference :- [Demo]https://snack.expo.io/H1a6!91kU

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, you want to center horizontally the `wrapper` view. For this, add `alignItems: 'center'` to your `container` style

Comment: Yup , it helped Thanks